# CUDA instructions ask to stop GDM but it doesn't exist

Tags: gui, gdm, cuda

I am trying to install and run some CUDA exemples in Ubuntu 12.04. First of all, I downloaded all .run files from http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads, then followed the instructions at http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-, until I got hung up on the first step:

> 1. Exit the GUI if you are in a GUI environment by pressing Ctrl-Alt-Backspace. Some
>      distributions require you to press this sequence twice in a row; others have disabled
>      it altogether in favor of a command such as sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop .
>      Still others require changing the system runlevel using a command such as
>      /sbin/init 3 to exit the GUI.

When I type the command `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm``stop`, it returns:
`gdm command not found`

Can anybody help me exit my GUI in order to continue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems when installing in 11.10 (I don't know if 12.04 is supported).

To exit the GUI, use `sudo service lightdm stop` (Ubuntu now uses lightdm instead of gdm).

Once you have exited the GUI, and before you run the install script, make sure to completely unload nVidia's kernel module. To do this, I used "dkms", but I don't remember the commands used.